# How can format GPS data to json

Tags: node-red

I have an message from MQTT which gives lat and long coordinates and I want to plot it on worldmap in node red.

I am confused how to show marker  on map by lat long please help.

I am using the worldmap in ui iframe which is given - under the menu (top right) - Import - Examples - Worldmap

The co-ordinate is in node red debug tab and console look like this:

```
object
topic: "location"
payload: "1,18.392378,76.593338,284.8"
qos: 0
retain: false
_msgid: "68d05896.c67388"
```

And in debug tab look:

```
location : msg.payload : string[27]
"0,18.394644,76.592491,224.7"
```

I want to convert it like this

```
{name:"Art", lat:18.394606, lon:76.592514}
```

to show the maker in world map

Comment: Edit the question to show what have you already tried

Comment: More importantly, you need to add a sample of the GPS data you are trying to plot -- without that we can only guess, and nobody has time for that...

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways to achieve this.

If you are familiar with JavaScript, you can use a simple function node. Alternatively, you can do it with a Change node using [JSONata](http://jsonata.org/).

### Example Flow

Here is an example flow that uses both methods for comparison:

```
[{"id":"7bc85438.5f05ac","type":"inject","z":"20e74d1e.f19692","name":"","topic":"","payload":"1,18.392378,76.593338,284.8","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":270,"y":560,"wires":[["923f0b9f.df87a8","87b267.8abfbd98"]]},{"id":"47bffe32.1be6f","type":"debug","z":"20e74d1e.f19692","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","x":630,"y":560,"wires":[]},{"id":"923f0b9f.df87a8","type":"function","z":"20e74d1e.f19692","name":"","func":"\nlet coord = msg.payload.split(',');\n\n\nmsg.payload = {\n    name:\"Art\", \n    lat: coord[1], \n    lon: coord[2]\n}\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":390,"y":560,"wires":[["47bffe32.1be6f"]]},{"id":"87b267.8abfbd98","type":"change","z":"20e74d1e.f19692","name":"","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"payload","pt":"msg","to":"(\t    $coord := $split(payload, ',');\t    \t    {\t        \"name\":\"Art\", \t        \"lat\": $coord[1], \t        \"lon\": $coord[2]\t    }\t)","tot":"jsonata"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":420,"y":600,"wires":[["47bffe32.1be6f"]]}]
```

### JavaScript for the function node:

```
let coord = msg.payload.split(',');


msg.payload = {
    name:"Art", 
    lat: coord[1], 
    lon: coord[2]
}

return msg;
```

### JSONata Code

```
(
    $coord := $split(payload, ',');

    {
        "name":"Art", 
        "lat": $coord[1], 
        "lon": $coord[2]
    }
)
```